# How to merge two images in qt after mirroring mode?

Tags: qt, qpainter, qimage

I need to mirror a image. I have that part accomplished, but the original image goes away in my image area when this function is called. I saved the original image and using QPainter drew the original then the mirrored, thinking both images would be composited. I'm still only getting the mirrored image. I want both the mirrored and the original image on my one image area. Here's what I have so far.

```
QImage* Original= mImage; //original image
QImage reflection = mImage->mirrored(true,false);//mirror the original image

QPainter painter(mImage);

painter.CompositionMode_DestinationOver;
painter.drawImage(0, 0, *mImage);
painter.drawImage(0, 0, reflection);
painter.end();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationOver
>
> The alpha of the destination is used to blend it on top of the source
>   pixels.

If your image doesn't have an alpha channel you won't see any difference.

Besides, you have other issues in your code.

- drawing the image on itself is unnecessary
- `painter.end();` is unnecessary
- setting composition mode is done with `painter.setCompositionMode();`
- composition mode is set between drawings

```
QPainter painter(mImage);
painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationOver);
painter.drawImage(0, 0, reflection);
```

Comment: Thanks, I created an alpha channel but now the mirroring isn't working
   `QImage mask = mImage->createAlphaMask();
   QPainter painter(&mask);`

Comment: You also need pixels with noticeable transparency.